# What to do to make two helper function return different values?

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
from collections import defaultdict

class ExtensionPoint:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__items = []

    def register(self, module, item):
        self.__items.append((module, item))

    def unregister_module(self, name):
        self.__items = [item for item in self.__items if item[1] != name]

priority = 1

class PluginFunctions:

    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = defaultdict(ExtensionPoint)

    def register(self, module, item):
        self.functions[priority].register(module, item)

    def unregister(self, item):
        self.functions[priority].unregister_module(item)

    def helper(self):
        print(self.functions)

obj = PluginFunctions()

obj. register("a","b")
obj.helper()
obj.unregister("b")
obj.helper()
```

Why this both helper function return same value? And how to make unregister function actually remove value from dict? I am not getting what is wrong with this code.

Comment: hey @vishal, can we clarify a few things? What exactly are you trying to do with this code? What is going wrong right now?

Comment: The contents of an `ExtensionPoint`'s `__items` don't actually affect how it prints in any way.

Comment: @peter dolan i am trying to register and unregister a module.

Comment: What the contents of self.functions in pluginfunction class doesn't change

Comment: The contents of `self.functions` doesn't change because you're not trying to change it, you're just mutating `self.functions[1]` in-place. Which seems to be working fine.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/FirebrickGlossyLead

Comment: How to change the content of self.functions in this context.

Comment: Why do you _want_ to change the content of `self.functions`? What's wrong with just mutating each `ExtensionPoint` in place, as your code is already successfully doing—click the `repl.it` link to see it happen.

Comment: More to the point, what do you want to change it _to_? A new dict with the same `ExtensionPoint` members? The same dict but with the member you mutated replaced by a copy of itself? …?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167366/discussion-between-vishal-choudhary-and-abarnert).